# The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly that is no longer available

Tags: c#, .net

I am going through some old code and I am having reference issues. On some of the project files. The error I am getting is this:

> The type 'XXXXX' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'AssemblyOne, Version=1.0.0'

Although it sounds strait forward, AssemblyOne version 1.0.0 no longer exists, and I need to use AssemblyTwo instead (Which has all the requirements to fulfill the content of AssemblyOne). I have already added the new AssemblyTwo to the project, and I am still getting this error. Both packages are NuGet packages.

So far I have already removed the reference to AssemblyOne from the packages.config and a `dependentAssembly` element in the app.config.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** It has been nearly a day and I am still having this issue. I'm 95% certain that I have obliterated any reference to AssemblyOne. This includes the packages.config, the app.config and even checking if anything is in `.csproj` files. Does anybody have a solution to how I can practically "ignore" the error that is appearing. Theoretically, if it would allow me to build the project/solution, it would work fine because all of the required contents/objects are available in AssemblyTwo.

Comment: Are you referencing a third assembly which uses type 'XXXXX' from AssemblyOne?

Comment: @AndyJ Had a look through the project. I have completely removed any reference to AssemblyOne from all projects. I think I may just be missing a step while doing something.

Comment: What line is causing the error? Is it a line trying to use 'XXXXX'? Or is it trying to use something, that uses 'XXXXX'? Also, you can try doing a "clean" and then a "rebuild" ... maybe it's gotten confused somewhere and it holding on to an old version of something? Sorry I don't have anything more solid for you :/

Comment: Add `-fl -flp:verbosity=detailed` to the msbuild command. It should give you enough info to figure out where the library is coming from in a file called `msbuild.log`.

Comment: You can't ignore the error - the compiler is loading *some* type from *some* assembly that, in turn, is still referencing `AssemblyOne`. It can't make any further progress without seeing that assembly. Check all of your references and ensure they're coming from clean locations (i.e. that you're not inadvertently referencing some assemblies from within a `bin` or `obj` directory). If that's not it, try a process of elimination - remove a reference, minimally comment out code that relies on that reference, attempt a compile - at some point, this particular error will go.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've had a look, couldn't find anything. Process of elimination may be difficult as there are 45 projects in the solution and practically everything relies on one another. Do you know of an extension or tool for VS 2017 which may help on what is referencing what?

Comment: Not that I recommend, no, this is probably surfacing other issues - 45 projects that cross-reference each other in a single solution is a little extreme (IME) - refactoring is probably long overdue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I managed to get it sorted anyway. There was a NuGet Package referenced which appeared to be having some strange problems (Saying that on of its own references it is up-to date when it was about four versions behind), removing the NuGet package and adding it as a project reference worked.